# Expression to search for a 10 digit specific number

Tags: regex

I am trying to write an expression that looks for a ten digit number that starts with 11 It needs to be able to find it in a paragraph or if user does not hit space and text is in front of it. here are some examples of what im trying to find and examples of what I need to search through.

- 1128647953 - Example of number looking for
- test1128647953test - Example of number looking for but just number no text
- Here is your number 1128647953 Thanks - Example of number looking for just number no text.

tried `11\d{8}` but it finds any number that has that combination in it and only want the specific number.

Comment: `(?<!\d)1128647953(?!\d)` - This will find the exact number. If you need to find any 10-digit number starting with that pattern, then `(?<!\d)11\d{8}(?!\d)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want portability, stick to standard regular expressions.  The canonical ERE  you're looking for should be:

```
[^0-9](11[0-9]{8})[^0-9]
```

Comment: this works for all but the example test1128647953test - Example of number looking for but just number no text brings up t1128647953t but did not get a syntax error. Just need the t's removed thanks for the help!!

Comment: I'm assuming only the pattern inside the `(` and `)` are being selected - you don't say how you're using it so it's hard to give a precise example.

Comment: I am using it in an email filter to find certain numbers to trigger on it is linux based. instead of the [^0-9] at beginning and end need something that tells it if any other number is in front or back it is not valid but if a letter is at the front or back then it is valid. sorry new to this probably just making it worse.

Comment: So the way im using it is if in an email it see a ten digit number starting with 11 and is ten digits then it will find it. but user are typing the info in so could forget spaces on either side of the number. any help thanks

Answer (score 2):

You were close. `(?<!\d)11\d{8}(?!\d)`

```
(?<!\d)     # negative look-behind: a position not preceded by a digit
11\d{8}     #
(?!\d)      # negative look-ahead: a position not followed by a digit
```

This matches sequence of digits exactly 10 places long unless they are embedded in a longer sequence of digits.

Comment: this works except if the number combination is in another number then it also finds that number example - 541128647953 anything to resolve it not finding this number also?

Comment: @Dan That was a typo, try again.

Comment: that works great in my expresso app but does not work in my email filter that is unix based. any suggestions?

Comment: get a syntax error assuming some characters are used for other purposes

Comment: @Dan What does "unix based" mean? What regular expression engine do you use and how do you use it?